# AngularJs + Rest Backend CSRF Security

Tags: angularjs, rest, csrf, csrf-protection

I am building a simple AngularJs web app that hits a REST Api built with Flask. From what I understand, there are a few ways to protect against CSRF, one of which is sending back a CSRF token when the user authenticates.

If I wanted to make my API available to both the Web Application and to users who want to use it as an API for development, would I need 2 endpoints for each endpoint that allows POST requests [one for the app that requires CSRF token + auth token and one for the developers that requires just an api access key]?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Broadly, you have two options:

1. Proxy the REST API through whatever server-side container your web app is running in. Your web-app proxy can then implement the CSRF protection and insert the API-key into the API request.
2. Check the referrer header on all API requests. Although this requires that your Angular SPA and API share the same authentication mechanism, so you'd have to use something more sophisticated than an API key, like OAuth.